# class instance inside static member function

Tags: php, function, class

I'm buliding user class for my server accounts. Is it smart to write a add() function, which invokes class instance itself? Isn't this a wrong aproach?

```
class cUser 
{
    private $login, $pass;   
    public static $users = array(), $userstmp, $datatmp, $usernew;   
    private static $datafile = "CuserData.txt";     

function __construct() 
{
    $this->login = $_POST['slogin'];
    $this->pass = $_POST['spass'];
}

public static function userAdd () 
{
    self::$usernew = new cUser();    //       <--- HERE ---<
    self::$users[ self::$usernew->login ] = self::$usernew;
    self::dataStore();
}
}
```

Comment: wrong approach. Why should the instance of `cUser` contain itself in it's own static property?

Comment: IMO, It's fine as long as you're going to follow a factory pattern.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, beacuse a static member isn't an instance?

Comment: but what for do that, if it can be done in constructor? seems little stupid now.